# Why does "git pull origin master" command removes the most recent merge commit?

Tags: git

I found that when I try "git pull origin master" command, sometimes the most recent commit is removed. It happens when I merge a local branch to the master, then pull from the remote origin.

Firstly I created a git repository with first commit. Currently local HEAD and origin/master points to the first commit (up to date).

```
$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
* d42ad4e (HEAD -> master, origin/master) First commit
```

Then I created a branch (branch name "test"), made a simple change and commit, and merged to the master.
After then, commit history looks following.

```
$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
*   ea13eb8 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'test'
|\
| * 9d3969f (test) test
|/
* d42ad4e (origin/master) First commit
```

As you can see, 9d3969f is the commit I made on test branch, and ea13eb8 is created via "git merge test" command.

Then if I use "git pull origin master" command,

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/????/????
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

```
$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate
* 9d3969f (HEAD -> master, test) test
* d42ad4e (origin/master) First commit
```

The change applied as I wanted, but commit ea13eb8 is deleted now. I'm just curious what happens to the most recent commit when I pull from the remote origin.

Comment: One more illustration of why `git pull` is bad.

Comment: See `True Merge` section of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: @matt `git pull` ultimately use `git merge` as fast-forward. It just takes changes from remote and apply `git merge` command on same branch. It is not bad, it is just normal way to get changes to local branch.

Comment: @Akshay I disagree.

Comment: @matt yes rebase it best way. git merge creates new commit that makes understanding of graph. But that doesn't mean `git pull` is bad way.

Answer (score 1):

The feedback you are getting from Git might partially reveal what is happening here:

> Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

It appears that your pull strategy is using rebase, rather than a simple merge.  As a result, when you `git pull`, a rebase is happening, which can rewrite history and also move around commits.  Check you `.gitconfig` file for an entry looking something like this:

```
[branch]
  autosetuprebase = always
```

You may also run the following to check your Git configuration:

```
git config --list
```

If you *don't* want the current behavior, then maybe it is time to change your settings.  Or, you could explicitly pull via the merge strategy using:

```
# from master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you use `git pull` using `rebase`.

Please refer [git rebase has empty commit behaviour](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_empty_commits)

By default git has `git merge` behaviour which adds merge commit.